# Equation of combustion of heavy fuel oil (HFO)

Tags: combustion, fuel

We are researching the use of heavy fuel oil (HFO) on ship vessels, but are having trouble finding the equation of the chemical combustion process of HFO. I understand that it contains long chains of hydrocarbons, however it would be helpful if someone could help us towards finding it.

$$\ce{CH4 + 2O2 + N2 + H2S -> 2H2O + CO2 + NO + NO2 + SO2}$$

So far we have found that the base equation, including pollutants in HFO, comes down to to the above according to [www.petroleum.co.uk](http://www.petroleum.co.uk/how-hydrocarbons-burn).

Comment: ["The chemical composition of HFO is highly variable due to the fact that HFO is often mixed or blended with cleaner fuels, blending streams can include carbon numbers from C20 to greater than C50."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_fuel_oil) There cannot be a single equation and it is highly dependent on the batch you are using. The general case you have for methane would work for many of the hydrocarbons $\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$ (and others) just fine, but that's just the resulting stoichiometry. The process might be more complex. Have you done any literature research?

Comment: There is nothing to be found. Heavy oil doesn't even have a single formula, much less a single equation of any reaction.

Comment: @IvanNeretinso so you suggest HFO doesn't combust at all? I understand that it is not a single formula, but i'm interested in the base equation which can be applied to longer chains of hydrocarbons. And if it really doesn't have any equation, point me towards a source since without a source it does not help me further.

Comment: Why, it surely does combust regardless of our inability to write an equation for that. (Likewise, planets used to rotate around the Sun long before Newton wrote his equations.) So what? Well, I guess you may write something along the lines of $$\ce{C_xH_y + \left(x + {y\over4}\right)O2 -> xCO2 + {y\over2}H2O}$$ but this is hardly very useful.

Comment: Also ring type hydrocarbons and likely compounds up to 4 + % if you mean "bunker C" . If you mean fuel for a Diesel type engine and not a boiler --- still could have many compounds.

Comment: You either need to know how much of each molecule you have and have a combustion equation for each one, or you need to use model compounds... lump all c10-c20 into being c15 and combust X amount of c15, lump c21-c30 into c25 etc.. or even just lump everything into c20 etc... Also, if you are combusting this as actual fuel oil, there better not be H2S in it, that will have been converted to other sulphur containing molecules by that point in the refining process.